# How to elegantly allow for lookups/dropdowns to be loaded with items marked 'Inactive' without totally messing up caching?

Tags: caching

Where the application has the ability to mark dropdown items 'inactive' - this means to the user that particular item is no longer in use and should not be shown in dropdowns.  However, it is used on existing files (has FK relation) and therefore cannot be 'deleted'.

When loading datasets for lookups, how to account for the value saved on the file which is now marked inactive?  By just loading all items NOT inactive, it will leave the field to show the user an Id (since the corresponding value not loaded in dropdown).

Just wondering about novel approaches that support caching.

I saw the post below, but it doesn't adequately answer the question IMO.  Thanks in advance!

[Deleting Lookup Item](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/194476/deleting-lookup-item)

Comment: You need to give us more contextual info, as we don't know what system you are working on, what it's supposed to do, and what technologies you are using. How is this dropdown used, what is it for? Why is it a problem that the value is missing from the dropdown? Why can't you just load all the data you need as required, and just filter out the dropdown items? You said: "it will leave the field to show the user an Id (since the corresponding value not loaded in dropdown)" - it is not clear what you mean.

Comment: Hi Filip. I think the language and tech stack doesn't matter, this should be fairly universal. If a field has an ID of an unloaded dropdown item, then the field will show the ID instead of the name of the lookup item.

Comment: Look, I'm not trying to debate you here, I'm trying to help you make the question better so that you could get a good answer. You haven't really answered any of my questions. Put yourself in our position - you could be describing a 100 different things. By providing us with more info, you are helping us help you. It's better to edit the post itself then to add info in the comments.

Comment: Based on what you've described so far: are you saying that you have some data-entry GUI where fields are represented (at all times) by dropdowns, but when a field is marked inactive, then it is not loaded and the dropdown just shows the FK? And that you want the value to show, but not be selectable in the dropdown? If so, then you may need to reconceptualize how your GUI works (e.g. show a label with an edit button that turns it into a dropdown). None of that was particularly clear from your question, BTW.